# How to get current logged user data in a RESTful way?

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have some trouble designing my API.

`GET /api/training-signups` - returns list of signups

`GET /api/training-signups/:id` - returns list of signups with the given `:id`

I want to get the signup list for the current logged in user. I've thought of different ways but all seem a bit wacky to me. Here is what I tried and what I don't like about it:

`GET /api/training-signups/me` - weird, instead of using an `:id` a "magic" `me` occurs

`GET /api/me/training-signups/me` - I would rather start with `/api/trainnig-signups` as this url is responsible for signups

What would be your approach of doing it?

Comment: you could use `GET /api/training-signups/user/id` and `GET /api/training-signups/user/me`

Answer (score 2):

How about giving the `GET /api/training-signups` some optional GET parameters to specify the query?

like:

```
GET /api/training-signups?userId=123
```